# Can my Facebook Page be removed/deleted by attackers Reporting it multiple times a day?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm the admin of a ~75,000 like page on Facebook. We are quite active, and our target group is in the 18-26 age bracket, which means, simply, that our community's blood is somewhat "boiling"...

Recently we have started posting material as part of an advertisement that some abusive users don't like. They do not want to unlike the page and move on, though.
I have been receiving threatening messages from `throwaway/fake` accounts on Facebook, through the Page, that if we don't stop advertising the material they don't like, they will gather a number of people and start spam-reporting my Page until it gets put down.

This has got me quite anxious. Can a certain number of reports from spam-accounts drop my Page? Do reports get individually processed? Or is there a threshold of reports that gets your Page automatically unlisted/removed once it has been passed?

We've put too much work into this page only to be removed by some people that don't like our content, if they abuse the Report system...

Any input would be appreciated. Facebook for Pages did not have a Contact-Us link for Support questions.

Answer (score 2):

If someone reports your Page to Facebook, Facebook will review the Page and remove anything that doesn't follow the [Facebook Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards). Facebook may also warn or disable the person responsible.

> Please keep in mind that reporting something to Facebook doesn't guarantee that it will be removed. You may see something you don't like on Facebook if it doesn't violate the **Facebook Terms**.

As per my knowledge, till the time you are not violating Facebook [policies](https://www.facebook.com/policies) / [terms](https://www.facebook.com/terms), they will not take your Page down. So make sure you are not violating any policy of Facebook, because they are very strict about this and take action, sometimes they won't even inform to users.

You can block those people who is bothering you and/or you can [report](https://www.facebook.com/help/263149623790594) about them to Facebook (use message screenshot what he/she has sent as a witness).